# Is it possible to record simultaneously record the call while playing audio in Restcomm?

Tags: restcomm

I'm trying out Restcomm and I wanted to know if there is any way to simultaneously record the call while playing audio.

​So far what I've been able to do is:

- Place a "Record" verb which records for 5 seconds.
- Place a "Play"​ verb in another module, which plays an audio file.
- Point the "Continue to" parameter in the "Record" verb to the module containing the "Play" verb.

When I call to a number with this controller, it records for 5 seconds, and then it plays the audio file.

​What I'm asking is if it's possible to record the audio input while playing the audio file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for a behaviour like Gather verb, that allows you to nest Say,Play and Pause verbs. http://docs.telestax.com/restcomm-rcml-gather/

As you can see, http://docs.telestax.com/restcomm-rcml-record/ doesn't allow nesting yet.

With that being said, the use case you describe is technically possible, so it's a matter of pushing this feature into the roadmap. Of course, contributions are always welcome!!